# Differentiate the Function $f(x) = \pi^2$

Tags: calculus

What does it mean to differentiate $\pi$? Is it similar to constant thus $0$?

Comment: Yes, that's right.

Comment: It's not "similar to constant", it **is** a constant.

Comment: yep,  this is a question I ask all my students.   If there's no variable, there's nothing changing...derivatives measure rate of change.   THus, no change=0 derivitave.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image: $y = \pi^2$]

Above is the plot for $f(x) = \pi^2$. Note that the slope at any point on this graph is zero. Hence, $f^\prime(x) = 0$.

Answer (score 2):

It does not matter what sort of constant it is, what really matters is that, it is a constant.
As we know, the derivatives of constants are $0$.

Answer (score 1):

"What does it mean to differentiate a constant?"

Imagine the following $\frac{f(x+dx)-f(x)}{dx}=\frac{\pi^2-\pi^2}{dx}$ The RHS is clearly zero. Therefore the derivative $\frac{df(x)}{dx}$ is also zero.